# Custom post type slug 404

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, 404-error

I have created a custom post type

```
public function register_post_types() {
    $args = array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => 'Android Apps',
            'singular_name' => 'Android App',
            'add_new' => 'Add New App',
            'add_new_item' => 'Add New App',
            'edit_item' => 'Edit App',
            'new_item' => 'New App',
            'view_item' => 'View App',
            'search_item' => 'Search App',
            'not_found' => 'No Apps Found',
            'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Apps Found in Trash'
        ),
        'query_var' => 'apps',
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'apps',
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'menu_icon' => admin_url(). 'images/media-button-video.gif', //Icon url
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'thumbnail',
            'editor',
        )
    );
    register_post_type('apps', $args);
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

The posts give a 404 on this style of permalinks http://site/apps/flashlight
[image: 404 page]

Although they work fine on plain permalinks
http://site/?apps=flashlight

[image: working]

Comment: Please refer at once **https://www.wpexplorer.com/post-type-404-error/**

Comment: @PratikPatel Hi i have checked all the given fixes as you can see from the code
i am flushing rewrite rules.
This is the only apps slug on a fresh wp install so no conflicts
.htaccess is there
it's just not working with SEO friendly permalinks which are enabled by default.
How to make it work?

Comment: have you try **'has_archive'        => true,** ?

Comment: yes, didn't work

Comment: Shouldn't the rewrite slug be without the trailing slash?

Comment: @Pim yes, i have tried that as well.

Comment: try to update your permalink from setting ( change to default and save and again change to posy by name and save)

Comment: Hello @MohamedRihan i have tried it multiple times. didn't work.

Comment: That’s your server’s 404 page, not your theme’s, which means the problem is your server, not WordPress

Comment: @Milo There's no error log at my server side i have mod_rewrite activated. what could be problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `with_front` in `rewrite` which is `true` by default. Change it to something like this

```
'rewrite' => array(
    'slug'          => 'apps',
    'with_front'    => false,
)
```

See the [docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#rewrite)

Bonus tip: You should avoid using `flush_rewrite_rules()` there, it's quite heavy and affects performance. You should ONLY use it when modifying `rewrite_rules` outside of `register_post_type()`, usually in plugin or theme activation/deactivation hooks.

Comment: Didn't work in my case. Tried.